# Xcode Error ITMS 90096 - I am not using any launch screens

Tags: ios, xcode

I have removed the launch screen file and removed all references from the info.plist file and in the main settings of the project the launch screen text field is empty.

What should I do?

Comment: my build target is IOS 7 and I am on JDK 9.2

Comment: You need all of the proper launch images.

Answer (score 1):

Based on other related questions, the ITMS 90096 error means your app isn't optimized for the iPhone 5.

Since you are supporting iOS 7 you must provide all of the appropriate launch images. You will need ones for 3.5" and 4" devices at a minimum. You should also provide ones for the 4.7" and 5.5" devices as well if you want happy users. And if your app is a universal app then you also need the iPad launch images.

You don't need a launch screen (<s>unless you want native support for the iPad Pro</s>*) but you must provide launch images.

* No longer true as of Xcode 8.

Comment: Would the best way to do this be via assets.xcassets and create a launchscreen? or via info.plist.

Comment: iOS 7 does support a launch screen. You can add one but it will only be used on iOS 8 and later. So you must provide launch images at a minimum. And yes, you a launch images image asset. It is much easier that way.

Comment: what should be in the text filed titled: "Launch screen file"? and there is something to do with launch screens in info.plist, does it need modifying?

Comment: If you are using launch images you leave the launch screen file blank. If you use an image asset for the launch images you don't need to do anything in Info.plist.